# PWA needs to access location when no wifi and no cellular

Tags: geolocation, gps, progressive-web-apps, offline

My client wants a mobile-app that can run with no WiFi and no cellular network available.  I think that a PWA gives them the most cost-effective way to meet their needs, accept that the app needs to know location even when there is no network available.  To do this the PWA would need access to the true-GPS, i.e., the info gathered by the GPS chip talking to the satellites.  It's my understanding that a PWA does not yet have this access and there is no date for when we can expect it.  Could we buy or develop a native mobile app that delivered the GPS-info to my PWA?  I've seen some discussion of this using Cordova, but I would like to avoid diving into that world if I can.

Comment: FYI - I believe the browser does not get location info when in the background. So, if you want to check the location when the user is not using your PWA, it may not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but we don't need the location info unless the user is running the PWA.  But because the user might be using the PWA far from cell towers, there might not be any cellular service.

Answer (score 0):

I put my Android into airplane-mode and took it for a walk around the block. The PWA that I had installed on the Android was still able to give me the updated location. So perhaps the discussions and complaints I see on stackoverflow, etc., regarding this not working, are out-of-date. BTW: In the navigator.geolocation options I have:

```
enableHighAccuracy: true
```

so hopefully the browser uses this as a hint to use the GPS-chip if available, and not care if there is no network available.